# Qt Creator and GCC

Tags: c++, native, qt-creator

How I can build native C++ files using Qt Creator. I want to write native C++ programs in Qt Creator and then build them using GCC.

How I can do it?

P.S. I am on Ubuntu 10.04 with Qt Creator 2.1.1

Comment: ** I want to build any *.cpp file (without qt project) using gcc. **

Comment: And also excuse me if my question is very stupid and must die)

Comment: Write the code, Compile it, Run it. ;-)

Comment: No. I want to compile NATIVE C++ Program without any *.pro files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a folder where you will store you project and run command:

```
qmake -project && qmake your_project.pro && make
```

2) Open your_project.pro and put some flags etc... like

```
   #c++0x
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
   #obj foldr
    unix:OBJECTS_DIR = ../your_project/obj
```

3) Go and open pro file with your qtcreator.

4) Enjoy coding :)